# Zxing Front Camera Mirror Image issue

Tags: android, android-camera, zxing, barcode-scanner

I am trying to use the front camera for the `zxing` barcode scanner on Android Tablet -- to make it work,i did the below changes:

1) GingerbreadOpenCameraInterface.java

```
 //    if (cameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK) { 
       if (cameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
```

2) CameraManager.java

```
 //   return new PlanarYUVLuminanceSource(data, width, height, rect.left, rect.top,
 //                                       rect.width(), rect.height(), false);  //changed false to true below 
      return new PlanarYUVLuminanceSource(data, width, height, rect.left, rect.top,
                                        rect.width(), rect.height(), true);
```

3) CameraConfigurationManager.java:

```
camera.setDisplayOrientation(180);  // added to rotate the image by 180 degrees as it ws already flipped once had changed to frontcamera
```

4) Also in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/> 
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false"/>
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false"/>
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" android:required="false"/>
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.landscape"/>
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" android:required="false"/>
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false"/>
```

It is scanning fine but the moment it scans and show a final few secs of preview image, there it shows an inverted image. Here is the link to the snapshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMU2X.png

So I have below question if anybody can help:

1) How to change the final preview inverted image to normal

2) Is there any way to remove the part where it shows the final few secs of the captured image.

Comment: Have your scanned the QR code in front camera? Would you please help me out. I am struggling there.

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually want to flip the image data from the front camera. It is presented to an app the way the camera sees it. When Android flings the image onto a `SurfaceView`, it will mirror it, since it is more intuitive that way. But you don't need to, and shouldn't, mirror it in your code. That flag exists from some time when there was some device that didn't work this way if I recall correctly.

It looks like you are integrating with something like Barcode Scanner by `Intent` though? No you can't control this aspect, since it's showing the image correctly! Then none of these manifest entries are needed.

If this is all embedded code, I don't understand why you are trigger the path that responds to `Intent`, since that's what you're showing. That raises further concerns: are you writing an app that responds to our Intents? That's bad, it inteferes with our app. Are you cloning our UI? that's not OK by the open source license.

Best thing truly is to start by writing your own UI and reuse only parts you know you need and know how they work. Then you will avoid a lot of this mess anyway.

Comment: Thanks Sean from the answer..But i do need to understand that what is the flag which you have mentioned above.Also I am sorry but I dont understand the concept of Intents (any documentation would be really helpful).. Also if possible is there any way i can completely remove the part where it shows the snapshot of the image for few secs just after it decoded something.Also I am not trying to clone the UI, I respect the Open Source Concept and really appreciate the hard work done by the whole Zxing team.

Comment: The flag is the boolean parameter you show changed above. The screen shot shows you calling Barcode Scanner by Intent. Or else you are reusing that UI screen. It's your app... you don't know? This usually happens when people are copying and pasting our app and I have to discourage that because it makes your app declare manifest entries that interfere with ours. You aren't granted trademark rights to the UI either. I would start on the right foot. If you can't write your own app use ours by Intent.

Comment: I am just trying to learn how to use a zxing library to create a barcode scanning android app using the https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/BarcodeScanner.. does using this with the License is a problem .. my intentions are really to start on the right foot and do what is right as I really appreciate the hard work of Zxing team.. So in any ways can I use the Barcode Scanner embedded in my App mentioning the MIT License which comes with the above link which I have mentioned.. Please correct me If I am missing something here..

Comment: Key points are don't clone the UI exactly, don't copy our manifest, and follow the terms of the Apache license.

Comment: 1) "don't clone the UI exactly"  -- Can i use something like mentioned in https://code.google.com/p/zxing/issues/detail?id=138          2)"don't copy our manifest"  -- What key changes can I make in the manifest file.   Any help here would be really appreciable..

Comment: Using Intents is the easiest way yes. That involves none of these problems. Otherwise be careful not to copy manifest entries for intent filters and do not use our package namespace.